# Super Secret Room with black poop and spikes

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth

Since the afterbirth DLC you can stumble upon super secret rooms with nothing but spikes and a black poop in the center of the room.

[image: Black Poop Room]

Is there anything more to it or is this just a "You get nothing!" type of thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never found anything useful in those rooms beyond what may or may not be in the poop. I wondered the same thing myself a while back and looked at a few different BoI wikis and forum posts and nothing indicated there was anything more in there.

Comment: I just tried to go in the black poop super-secret room with the "Yo listen!" item. It focused at a specific place, in the water close to the path. So there IS something? I tried bombing it, fly over it but found nothing... yet.